# What code that has same function as 'Picture1.Cls' (VB 6) in visual basic 2010?

Tags: vb.net

is there any code or something i can do in visual basic 2010 that has same function as `picture1.Cls` in visual basic 6?

i want to clear the picture box in my barcode application project, so everytime i change (erase/add string) in textbox, it will always convert the actual string in the textbox. because now everytime i change the text its like didnt want to change the last image that has been converted.

here is my code :

```
Private Sub make39()
.
.
.
.
.
.

'PictureBox1.Invalidate()
        'PictureBox1.Refresh()
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
        pos = 5
        Bardata = UCase(TextBox1.Text)

 temp = BC(43) & "0" & temp & BC(43)

        'Generate Barcode
        For x = 1 To Len(temp)
            If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
                'SPACE
                pos = pos + 1 + (2 * Val(Mid$(temp, x, 1))) + 1
            Else
                'BAR
                For y = 1 To 1 + (2 * Val(Mid$(temp, x, 1)))
                    'PictureBox1 (pos, 1) - (pos, 58 - 1 * 8)
                    'Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Black)
                    'ga.DrawLine (pos, 1)-(pos, 58 - 1 * 8)
                    ga = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
                    ga.DrawLine(Pens.Black, pos, 1, pos, 58 - 1 * 8)
                    'ga.DrawLine(Pens.Black, New Point(pos, 1), New Point(pos, 58 - 1 * 8))
                    pos = pos + 1
                Next
            End If

        Next
        ga.DrawString(TextBox1.Text, New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10), Brushes.Red, New System.Drawing.Point(90 + Len(Bardata) * (5 + 1 * 2), 55))
        temp = 0
    End Sub
```

as you can see in the code ive been trying to use `PictureBox1.Refresh` and `PictureBox1.Invalidate` to trying clear my picturebox. also at the last code i define 'temp' to 0. i just want to expect that everytime i change the textbox it always converted the new barcode.

thanks for your kindness and sorry for my bad english

Comment: NEVER call `CreateGraphics`. If you want to draw on a control, handle its `Paint` event and do your drawing in the event handler using the `Graphics` object provided. Any time you want to change the drawing, call `Invalidate` on the control to raise a `Paint` event and execute your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, never call `CreateGraphics`. Handle the `Paint` event of the control you want to draw on and use the `Graphics` object provided. Any time you want to execute that drawing code, call `Invalidate` on the control to raise a `Paint` event. E.g.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox1.Text, Font, Brushes.Black, PointF.Empty)
End Sub
```

Comment: it must be filled as 'e As PaintEventArgs' or it can be filled 'ByVal e As PaintEvenArgs'?

Comment: @afkaar, `ByVal` has always been the default for VB.NET and I think it was VB 2008 where they made it optional and implicit. You can include it if you want but there's no point to doing so in any method, while omitting it makes code less cluttered and thus more readable. If you use VB 2008 or later then, when the IDE creates event handlers for you, it won't include `ByVal` explicitly.

Comment: ok then, since i call the sub 'PictureBox1_Paint(PictureBox1, ) i got error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.  what object to fill the 'PaintEventArgs' when i want to call the sub

Comment: @afkaar, and why would you be doing that in the first place? Nowhere in my answer did I suggest that you should do that. Read what I wrote and do what I said.

Comment: aight, maybe i need to read and understanding again what you said. thanks a lot sir